# How to build unmanaged function which simply gets class Input and returns class Output?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have unsafe class `Multipolynomial`:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe class Multipolynomial
{
    private int _n;
    private int _max_power;

    //get/set code below for _n and _max_power
    ...

    public double* X { get; set; }
    public double** Y { get; set; }
}
```

and I have two classes containing exclusively doubles and Multipolynomials properties kind of:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe class Input
{
    public double S_M { get; set; }
    public Multipolynomial C_x_M { get; set; }
    ...
    public Input()
    {
        C_x_M = new Multipolynomial();
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe class Output
{
    //very same as Input
    ...
}
```

and there is function `dummy_solution` with unmanaged signature

```
KERNEL_API output dummy_solution(input *in_p);  //input and output are unmanaged structs
```

and managed signature

```
[DllImport("kernel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Output dummy_solution(Input in_p);
```

The problem is when Im trying to execute code

```
Input input = new Input();
Output output = new Output();
MathKernel.no_solution(input);  //works great except it does nothing and returns nothing =P
output = MathKernel.dummy_solution(input);  //does nothing, simply returns empty Output object and crashes
```

it threw exception `XamlParseException` with inner exception `{"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}`.

`no_solution` function is just dummy test function with unmanaged signature

```
KERNEL_API void no_solution(input *in_p);
```

and managed signature

```
[DllImport("kernel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void no_solution(Input in_p);
```

Hence I concluded that there is something wrong with returning Output object.
Honestly said Im newbie to such monstrous things as marshaling so maybe there are ugly stupid mustakes which I cannot see.

Please point out whats wrong or give an advice **how to build unmanaged function which simply gets class Input and returns class Output**.

Comment: Output needs to be a struct, it cannot be a class.

Comment: So there is no way to return class?
I rewrote Output to be a struct but nothing changed

Comment: I rethought this question and looks like I found where is the problem may be, so I created another (clearer) question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200615/return-marshal-struct-with-class-field-from-unmanaged-to-managed-code
And yes, class cannot be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PInvoke cannot have non-blittable types as a return value.
The easiest way is to make all classes structs.

[Nested struct unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200615/nested-struct-unmarshalling)