# Nested struct unmarshalling

Tags: c#, c, struct, return, unmarshalling

There are two unmanaged structs

```
typedef struct multipolynomial
{
    int N;
    int max_power;
    double* X;
    double** Y;
} multipolynomial;

typedef struct output
{
    double d;
    multipolynomial mp;
} output;
```

and corresponding managed analogs

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe class Multipolynomial
{
    public int n;
    public int max_power;
    public double* X;
    public double** Y;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct Output
{
    public double d;
    public Multipolynomial mp;
}
```

And there is native function

```
__declspec(dllexport) output __cdecl foo()
{
    output out;
    out.t = 1;
    return out;
}
```

with managed signature

```
[DllImport("kernel.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern Output foo();
```

that crashes here

```
Output output = MathKernel.foo();
```

with explanation "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible."

Please point out whats going wrong?

PS: please note that managed analogue for Multipolynomial struct is **class**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx): P/Invoke cannot have non-blittable types as a return value. That's why you are getting the error you are getting. Also, your managed definitions don't match your unmanaged definitions. The unmanaged `output` contains `multipolynomial` by value, but your managed equivalent contains it by reference (besides, object references are not blittable). The managed `Multipolynomial` must be a struct, and you must specify `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]` on the `mp` field — see [MarshalAs nested structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914802/marshalas-nested-structure). In addition, I am unsure whether unsafe pointers are blittable. Replace them with `IntPtr`s while you are testing this out, then put the pointers back in.

Comment: thank you! I will try this out and let you know whether it works

Comment: Looks like it works! Thank you! I made all classes to be structs and
moreover it works for me with only attribute [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]